# how to get a kind of "maximum" in a matrix, efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, matrix, iteration

I have the following problem: I have a matrix opened with `pandas` module, where each cell has a number between -1 and 1. What I wanted to find is the maximum "posible" value in a row that is also not the maximum value in another row.

If for example 2 rows has their maximum value at the same column, I compare both values and take the bigger one, then for the row that has its maximum value smaller that the other row, I took the second maximum value (and do the same analysis again and again).

To explain myself better consider my code

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = pd.read_csv("matrix.csv") 
# this matrix has an id (or name) for each column 
# ... and the firt column has the id of each row
results = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((len(matrix),3),dtype=pd.Timestamp),columns=['id1','id2','max_pos'])

l = len(matrix.col[[0]]) # number of columns

while next = 1:
   next = 0
   for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
       max_column = str(0)
       for j in range(1, l): # 1 because the first column is an id
           if matrix[max_column][i] < matrix[str(j)][i]:
               max_column = str(j)
       results['id1'][i] = str(i) # I coul put here also matrix['0'][i]
       results['id2'][i] = max_column
       results['max_pos'][i] = matrix[max_column][i]

   for i in range(0, len(results)): #now I will check if two or more rows have the same max column
       for ii in range(0, len(results)):
       # if two id1 has their max in the same column, I keep it with the biggest 
       # ... max value and chage the other to "-1" to iterate again
           if (results['id2'][i] == results['id2'][ii]) and (results['max_pos'][i] < results['max_pos'][ii]):
               matrix[results['id2'][i]][i] = -1
               next = 1
```

Putting an example:

```
#consider
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 5, 0], 'b':[4, 5, 1, 0], 'c':[3, 3, 4, 2], 'd':[1, 0, 0, 1]})

   a  b  c  d
0  1  4  3  1
1  2  5  3  0
2  5  1  4  0
3  0  0  2  1

#at the first iterarion I will have the following result

0  b  4 # this means that the row 0 has its maximum at column 'b' and its value is 4
1  b  5
2  a  5
3  c  2

#the problem is that column b is the maximum of row 0 and 1, but I know that the maximum of row 1 is bigger than row 0, so I take the second maximum of row 0, then:

0  c  3
1  b  5
2  a  5
3  c  2

#now I solved the problem for row 0 and 1, but I have that the column c is the maximum of row 0 and 3, so I compare them and take the second maximum in row 3 

0  c  3
1  b  5
2  a  5
3  d  1

#now I'm done. In the case that two rows have the same column as maximum and also the same number, nothing happens and I keep with that values.

#what if the matrix would be 
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 5, 0], 'b':[5, 5, 1, 0], 'c':[3, 3, 4, 2], 'd':[1, 0, 0, 1]})

   a  b  c  d
0  1  5  3  1
1  2  5  3  0
2  5  1  4  0
3  0  0  2  1

#then, at the first itetarion the result will be:

0  b  5
1  b  5
2  a  5
3  c  2

#then, given that the max value of row 0 and 1 is at the same column, I should compare the maximum values
# ... but in this case the values are the same (both are 5), this would be the end of iterating 
# ... because I can't choose between row 0 and 1 and the other rows have their maximum at different columns...
```

This code works perfect to me if I have a matrix of 100x100 for example. But, if the matrix size goes to 50,000x50,000 the code takes to much time in finish it. I now that my code could be the most inneficient way to do it, but I don't know how to deal with this.

I have been reading about threads in python that could help but it doesn't help if I put 50,000 threads because my computer doesn't use more CPU. I also tried to use some functions as `.max()` but I'm not able to get column of the max an compare it with the other max ...

If anyone could help me of give me a piece of advice to make this more efficient I would be very grateful.

Comment: `What I wanted to find is the maximum "posible" value in a row that is also not the maximum value in another row.` - What should happen when multiple rows *do* have the same maximum value?

Comment: For example, if column 3 has the maximum value for the rows 2 and 4, I compare the value between row 2 and 4. Suppose that the value in row 2 is bigger than row 4, in that case I leave that maximum to row 2 and take the second maximum of row 4 (and then, another column will be the maximum). If both row 2 and row 4 values are the same, then I don't change nothing.

Comment: @hllspwn Thats a very confusing comment. Could you put in your question, something reproducible to show us what you mean. Create a very basic table like `pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 4], 'b':[4, 5, 1], 'c':[3, 3, 4]})` And tell us what you want to see from it.

Comment: Done, sorry if could not explain myself before, I hope that the example helps. Thanks for the piece of advice @Matt W.

Comment: No need to apologize! And thanks for the clarification, it now makes much more sense. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: One other question - what happens if the same column has the same max value for multiple rows? in your example switch the 4 in column b with a 5, and go through your logic.

Comment: I add that case to the question's examples

Answer (score 1):

Going to need more information on this. What are you trying to accomplish here?

This will help you get some of the way, but in order to fully achieve what you're doing I need more context.

We'll import numpy, random, and Counter from collections:

```
import numpy as np
import random 
from collections import Counter
```

We'll create a random 50k x 50k matrix of numbers between -10M and +10M

```
mat = np.random.randint(-10000000,10000000,(50000,50000))
```

Now to get the maximums for each *row* we can just do the following list comprehension:

```
maximums = [max(mat[x,:]) for x in range(len(mat))]
```

Now we want to find out which ones are not maximums in any other rows. We can use `Counter` on our maximums list to find out how many of each there are. Counter returns a counter object that is like a dictionary with the maximum as the key, and the # of times it appears as the value.
We then do dictionary comprehension where the value is == to 1. That will give us the maximums that only show up once. we use the `.keys()` function to grab the numbers themselves, and then turn it into a list.

```
c = Counter(maximums)
{9999117: 15,
9998584: 2,
9998352: 2,
9999226: 22,
9999697: 59,
9999534: 32,
9998775: 8,
9999288: 18,
9998956: 9,
9998119: 1,
...}

k = list( {x: c[x] for x in c if c[x] == 1}.keys() )

[9998253,
 9998139,
 9998091,
 9997788,
 9998166,
 9998552,
 9997711,
 9998230,
 9998000,
...]
```

Lastly we can do the following list comprehension to iterate through the original maximums list to get the indicies of where these rows are.

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(maximums) if x in k]
```

Depending on what else you're looking to do we can go from here.

Its not the speediest program but finding the maximums, the counter, and the indicies takes 182 seconds on a 50,000 by 50,000 matrix that is already loaded.